# Laravel : Form e ir buscar o ID

Tags: banco-de-dados, laravel, formulário

Existe alguma forma de ir buscar o ID (para guardar na BD) e o nome para o utilizador selecionar ?

```
    <option selected>Escolher Capitulo</option>

    @foreach($capitulos as $cap)
      <option class="form-control" id="id_capitulo" name="id_capitulo"> 
        {{$cap->capitulo}}
      </option>
    @endforeach 
</select>
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu não sei se entendi muito bem a pergunta, mas vou tentar mesmo assim. Você gostaria de enviar para o controller o ID do capítulo e na view mostrar o nome do capítulo? Neste caso é só colocar o id no valor da option:

```
<option class="form-control" id="id_capitulo" value="{{$cap->id}}" name="id_capitulo"> {{$cap->capitulo}}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

algo do tipo assim

```
$articles = Article::whereHas('tags', function($query) use ($tagName) {
```

$query->whereName($tagName);
})->get();

Segue o link da resolução que uma parte da resolução, pode resolver a sua questão.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49462916/find-all-posts-associated-with-a-tag-in-laravel